# How do I stop sitewide image from Scrolling?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a full-width paneled website. An image I am using at 100% width is horizontally scrolling. I've tried overflow: hidden to try to stop it but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

CSS:

```css
#widthwrapper {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#imgbg {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  float:clear;
margin: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
display:block;
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   z-index: 0;
   color:white;
   font-size:50px;
   font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   text-align:center;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<section id='panel1'>
<img id='bgimg' src='herobackground.png'/>
<div id='widthwrapper'>
<h2>Where would you like to go?</h2>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Overflow-y on parent only applies when you set its height explicitly and the child outgrows its parent horizontally. Otherwise it has no effect. Again setting overflow on the image has no effect because it is not a container element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say much with your code, but if you want your images to be responsive then you have to set `img { max-width:100%}` in your css.

Comment: This has worked, thank you so much! So stupidly simple and I didn't think of it. Thank you :D